# jQuery :not() + nth-child

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Having the following DOM structure:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="click_here"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="click_here"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="click_here"></li>
</ul>
```

I´m trying to add class "last" every 5 "li", but excluding the ones having class "click_here".

I´ve found out that this is not working:

```
$('ul li:not(.click_here)').filter(':nth-child(5n)').addClass('last');
```

I´ve also tried several ways of doing it, like:

```
$('ul li').filter(':not(.click_here)').filter(':nth-child(5n)').addClass('last');
$('ul li').not($('.click_here')).filter(':nth-child(5n)').addClass('last')
```

It doesn´t seem to skip "li" items having class "click_here".

So I´ve finally had to do it like this:

```
        $.each($('ul li').filter(':not(.click_here)'),function(i,v){
            if((i+1)%5 == 0) $(this).addClass('last');
        });
```

Does any of you know by any chance what am I doing wrong in my first approaches?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you understand what the snippets you give actually do? For example, `$('ul li').filter(':not(.click_here)').end()` is totally meaningless and leaves me with doubts.

Comment: Also, what does "every 5th li but excluding .click_here" mean? Every 5th if you take .click_here out of the question, or every 5th but if one of those is a .click_here it shouldn't get the class?

Comment: The 'end()' thing shouldn´t be there. Code updated.
And thanks Jon, but I think the explanation is clear.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `.filter()` at all? You should be able to just use `$('ul li:nth-child(5n):not(.click_here)')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can use nth-child, but try

```
$('ul li:not(.click_here)').filter(function (i) {
    return i % 5 == 4
}).addClass('last');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yH6Rw/)

Answer (score 2):

This version with nth-child works fine:

```
$('ul').find('li:not(".click_here")').filter(':nth-child(5n)').addClass( 'last' );
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/yPDn8/)

```js
$('ul').find('li:not(".click_here")').filter(':nth-child(5n)').addClass( 'last' );
```

```css
.last {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #000;
    background-color:#ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li class="click_here">
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li class="click_here">
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li class="click_here">
</ul>
```